# module not being imported correctly in python

Tags: python, module, import

when i attempt to import the following module (ex25.py):

```
def break_words(stuff): 
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
```

all i get back is this:

```
>>>import ex25
```

and nothing back...no prompt as to what i did wrong...its almost like it is not even reading the module...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are supposed to type all the lines that start with `>>>`

```
import ex25
sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = ex25.break_words(sentence) 
words
```

after you type the last line, `words`, you should see some output from the interpreter

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've actually done anything wrong; the `import` statement normally does not produce any output (it only complains if there *is* something wrong). Try:

```
>>> dir(ex25)
```

That should give a list of the names exported from the `ex25` module.

Comment: # after i enter the prompt in terminal
 >>> import ex25 
# im supposed to see the following                                  6 >>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
7 >>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
8 >>> word

Comment: No, that's what you're supposed to *type* next. Everything following `>>>` is a line you type into the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

type:

```
import ex25
ex25.break_words('some example')
```

or another way:

```
from ex25 import break_words
break_words('some example')
```

btw if the module wasn't found you would get an ImportError exception